# Swift transition unbalanced calls error using present and fullScreen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift5

I am presenting views with `.present`.
When the app loads the first view is loginView which is loaded from mainView which is the top controller.

All views are presented in a dedicated method. I can see clearly that at this time no other views are being presented.

I do not want views to be dismissible with a swipe. To achieve this I am using `.fullScreen`. When I use full screen I see the error/warning "*unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions*". Using 'fullScreen' the views belonging to the presenting view controller are removed after the presentation completes. I suspect that this is the cause of the message.

If I use `.overFullScreen` I do not see this message. Using `.overFullScreen` the views beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes.

Can anyone confirm that built in action of removing views following the `fullScreen` transition are the cause of this message and how can I use `fullScreen` without triggering this message.

Using Swift 5 and Xcode 13.4.1, Mac OS 12.2.1

```
func presentView(viewInstance: UIViewController){
    if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        viewInstance.modalPresentationStyle = . fullScreen
        topController.present(viewInstance, animated: false, completion: nil)
     }
}

extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```